# Trying to mock a function return in node.js/express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test an application I'm writing in node.js/Express.

I want to mock the return of a mock-repository I've set up for development purposes.

Mock repo:

```
let dogs = [];

export const getDogs = () => {
  return dogs;
};

export const setDogs = (updatedDogs) => {
  dogs = updatedDogs;
};
```

I'm importing the function to mock a return value from in my test file;

```
import * as sut from "../dogs.js";
import * as dogsRepo from "../../repositories/dogs.js";
import { mockRequest, mockResponse } from "mock-req-res";
import { jest } from "@jest/globals";

describe("dogs controller", () => {
  describe("getDogs", () => {
    test("should return dogs", () => {
      // Arrange
      const req = mockRequest();
      const res = mockResponse();
      // dogsRepo.getDogs = jest.fn().mockReturnValue([]);
      // jest.spyOn(dogsRepo, "getDogs").mockReturnValue([]);
      jest.spyOn(dogsRepo, "getDogs").mockImplementation(() => []);

      //Act
      sut.getDogs(req, res);
    });
  });
});
```

I simply want my test to mock a return value of [] from the repository. I have done this many times in react projects but this is my first time doing so in node.js.

I have tried to mock the return of the function in three different ways and each one gives me the error;

"TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'getDogs' of object '[object Module]'"

I import in the same way in the controller (sut) and it works as expected so I can feel reasonably confident that the style of import/export I'm employing is working.

```
import * as dogsRepo from "../repositories/dogs.js";

export const getDogs = (req, res) => {
  const dogs = dogsRepo.getDogs();
  res.send(dogs);
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Could it have something to do with this configuration in my package.json?

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js",
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you are not mocking the module. Try something like the following:

```js
jest.mock('../../repositories/dogs');
```

And your test should work. for more info, see the [official jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks).